# Find a matrix $B=A^{2021}-5A^{2020}+2A^{2019}+5A^{2018}-3A^{2017}+A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUsIF.png)

If $A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 2&  -1&  2\\
 -1&  2&  -1\\
 1&  -1&  2\\
\end{matrix} \right) $,

then how to find a
matix $B=A^{2021}-5A^{2020}+2A^{2019}+5A^{2018}-3A^{2017}+A^2?$

Comment: The first 5 terms sum to 0. Just factor A**2017 out to see it

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If $p(x)$ is a polynomial such that $p(A)=0$ and you divide that huge polynomial $g(x)$ by $p(x)$ you get $g(x)=p(x)q(x)+r(x)$, with $0\leq \deg(r)<\deg(p)$. Evaluating in $x=A$ you get $g(A)=r(A)$. [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) tells that we can take $p(x)$ to be the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which has degree $3$. So, finding $r$ will help us only have to evaluate on $A$ a polynomial of degree at most $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 2&  -1&  2\\
 -1&  2&  -1\\
 1&  -1&  2\\
\end{matrix} \right) $, then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+8x-3.$ Let $g(x)=x^{2021}-5x^{2020}+2x^{2019}+5x^{2018}$, then $g(x)=(x^{2018}+x^{2017})f(x)+x^2$.

Thus $B=A^2=\left( \begin{matrix}
 7&  -6&  9\\
 -5&  6&  -6\\
 5&  -5&  7\\
\end{matrix} \right).$